# Set proper cluster name to GridGain web console

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, gridgain

I am using two Gridgain clusters in Kubrenetes and they manage and monitor using single web console free version. Both clusters connected properly and working as I expected. But cluster name automatically generated and haven't any sense to identify cluster. Have any way to set proper cluster name for clusters in Gridgain web console. My dashboard view like this  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRTJ9.png)

Comment: First of all, such [question should be addressed to the vendor's support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions). As for topic related, from what I found in their docs, [name of the cluster can be setup](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/installation-guide/operator/operator-configuration#cluster_name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $ control.sh --change-tag <new-tag>

source: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#cluster-id-and-tag